# Joomla: If user has access level X, then

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I want to show some content only if a user belongs to the access level with the IDs 4 and 5. It should start with something like that:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

and then I need to check the access level of the logged in user.
Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe with  `$usertype = $user->get('usertype');`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```
<?php
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $levels = $user->getAuthorisedViewLevels();

    if(in_array(4, $levels) && in_array(5, $levels)) :
?>

        Content

<?php endif; ?>
```

Reference: [JUser::getAuthorisedViewLevels](https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JUser::getAuthorisedViewLevels) - 
[getAuthorisedViewLevels](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JUser.html#method_getAuthorisedViewLevels)

Hope this helps